# Is there a way to remove characters from data returned from an API?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: This is what API returns]I'm making a website using themoviedb api, and when asking for the movie release date, it returns the year of release, but it returns the year, month and day respectively and i would like to know if there is any way to remove the characters until only the year remains.

Here is my code:

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");

getMovies(URL_API);

async function getMovies(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();

  showMovies(data.results);
}

function showMovies(movies) {
  main.innerHTML = "";

  movies.forEach((movie, index) => {
    if (index >= 10) return;
    const {
      title,
      poster_path,
      vote_average,
      overview,
      vote_count,
      release_date,
    } = movie;

    const movieEl = document.createElement("div");
    movieEl.classList.add("movie");

    movieEl.innerHTML = `
        <a href="movie.html">
            <img src="${IMAGE_URL + poster_path}" alt="${title}"/>
        </a>
        <div class="movie-info">
            <a href="movie.html">
                <h3>${title}</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="movie-rate">
        <img class ="star" src="imgs/star.svg"  alt="heart">
        </div>
        <h4>${vote_average}</h4>
        <h5>${release_date}</h5>
    `;
    main.appendChild(movieEl);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide some examples of what `release_date` contains and how you'd like to display it. Also, show what you've tried

Comment: You can edit the api data and expected output into the question, which will make it easier to understand what you want

Comment: If it's an ISO 8601 date string like `1999-10-12`, can you not simply use `release_date.substring(0, 4)`?

Comment: You can do something like `new Date(release_date).getFullYear()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` on release_date so it would return an array and then you can retrieve the year.
Eg, if release_data = '2000-05-04' then use,

```
const year = release_date.split('-')[0]
```